# Can i get false return type

Tags: java, exception, dao

In the try block, I am hoping that the status variable will change to true and a successful return will be sent. I do not want to send false return type.

Instead, I want to throw error if return type would be false. **Can i have a situation where a false return type is sent**.

```
public boolean updateSchool(String username, String password, String school) throws Exception {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(userName);
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                user.setSchool(school);
                userDao.save(user);
                status = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Easy. Don't catch the exception. It will be passed up the stack.

Comment: @TrippKinetics It's rethrown.

Comment: You apparently know how to use an `if` and how to throw an exception. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Btw, what's the point of a return value if it's always the same?

Comment: In the try block, return type is set to true.  I don't want status to have false value that is why i want to throw an error.

Comment: @karna but it can never be false... if an exception is thrown, the execution will immediately stop

Comment: But why are you throwing an exception anyway?

Comment: If the if condition is not met it will return false

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
public boolean updateSchool(String username, String  password, String school) throws Exception {
        User user = userDao.findByUsername(userName);
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                user.setSchool(school);
                userDao.save(user);
               status = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Could not update School.");
        }
       finally{
             if(!status){
                 throw new Exception("status is false");
              }
        }
       }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two "problems":

1. there is no sense to re-throw exception
2. there is no sense in constant return value

its better to write something like this:

```
public void updateSchool(String username, String password, String school) throws Exception {
    User user = userDao.findByUsername(userName);
    if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        user.setSchool(school);
        userDao.save(user);
    }
}
```

this method either finish successfully or throw exception in case of error

Comment: The thing is i need the return type that will be used in jsp page.

Comment: @karna why do you need to test for a value which is always true?